# Does Z3 support Real-to-Int conversions?

Tags: z3

In Z3 you have to_real to obtain the Real equivalent of an Int. Is there some support to the inverse conversions, i.e., to truncation, rounding or like? In the negative case, what could be the most Z3-friendly way of defining them, if any? Many thanks to everyone will answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, Z3 has a `to_int` function that converts a Real into an integer. The semantics of `to_int` is defined in the [SMT 2.0 standard](http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/theories/Reals_Ints.smt2). Here is an example: http://rise4fun.com/Z3/uJ3J

```
(declare-fun x () Real)

(assert (= (to_int x) 2))
(assert (not (= x 2.0)))

(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

Comment: Thank you very much; since I need round-towards-zero I will use (define-fun round_to_zero ((x Real)) Int (if (>= x 0.0) (to_int x) (- (to_int (- x))))). Thank you again, and keep on with the nice work with Z3.