# Implement floor as an expression, not a statement

Tags: z3

Is it possible to express floor such that it can be used as an expression instead of a statement? In Yices, we can do something like this, which yields `sat` and `(= fooInt 5)`:

```
(define floor::(-> x::real (subtype (y::int) (and (<= y x) (< x (+ y 1)))))) 
(define fooReal::real 11/2)
(define fooInt::int)
(assert (= fooInt (floor fooReal))
```

The closest I can get in Z3 is the following (I think since Z3 does not support dependent types):

```
(declare-const fooInt Int)
(define-fun fooReal () Real 5.5)
(assert (and (>= fooReal fooInt)(< fooReal (+ fooInt 1))))
```

Floor as an expression is ideal since it would more closely match the AST I'm generating the Z3 input from. My apologies if I've missed an obvious solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you can exploit the semantics of `to_int` as specified in SMT-LIB2 (see http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/theories/Reals_Ints.smt2) to take the floor using a function (rise4fun link: http://rise4fun.com/Z3/da5I):

```
(define-fun floor ((x Real)) Int
  (to_int x))

(declare-const fooInt Int)
(define-fun fooReal () Real 5.5)
(assert (= fooInt (floor fooReal)))
(check-sat) ; sat
(get-model) ; 5

(assert (> fooInt 5))
(check-sat) ; unsat
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for, but again, I lack the reputation to upvote upvote... Thanks! :)

Comment: Sure, also you may find this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12896440/does-z3-support-real-to-int-conversions/12897438#12897438